# C# VS 2013 Designer not loading UI elements

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I recently did a fresh install of Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 on my laptop (Dell Inspiron 15 3251) and this bug has occured.

When in projects that use the "old" Silverlight framework (for Windows Phone 8.0) or making Windows Store Apps, the designer loads just fine with all the elements being visible, however, when I try to make or open a project that uses Windows RunTime (Windows Phone 8.1 apps) the designer isn't showing the UI elements, I can see their borders when I select them, but they are not visible.

I read that setting my AMD per application settings for Visual Studio to maximum performance would fix the problem, but that did not help at all.

Comment: try repairing installation..

Comment: @MangeshGhotage I've tried repairing, then reinstalling Visual Studio, did not help. Also tried reinstalling my graphics drivers.

Comment: can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @MangeshGhotage Sure, here it is [img](http://i.imgur.com/R2thwaJ.png)